# Is there a way to change windows local account profile to a domain account profile?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, user-profiles, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate desktop user to domain user](https://superuser.com/questions/76897/migrate-desktop-user-to-domain-user)

I have a user who has been using her local windows xp user profile.  Now with Active Directory implementation, I want to have the same profile associated to her new domain account profile.  I know I can transfer files and folders manually. But I want to know if there is a way to associate profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My answer from a duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/76897/migrate-desktop-user-to-domain-user/76902#76902):

Easiest way to transfer your profile to the domain is :

Go to system properties by Control Panel > System, or the easiest way is to press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>.

Go to the advanced tab (XP and before), or click on "Advanced system settings" (Vista and 7).

(You may have to start by changing type to "Roaming Profile")

Click settings under "User Profiles", then find your user and choose the copy to option. Simply choose \servername and wherever your profiles are kept.

[image]

With Active Directory users and computers, make this the profile path and next time you login, it should pull this profile from the server.

Comment: The "Copy To" is not available other than Default Profile. I've use "Windows Enabler" to reenable the button, and later I still need to copy Local & Local Low in AppData folder from the original profile to the new profile manually, to have every single thing copied properly

Comment: @Faulty - you really shouldn't much around with `Windows Enabler` on system stuff... Anyway, it will not work on the same user you are logged in under - try creating a new profile or enabling guest (but give guest admin privileges temporarily), then, log in and try again.

Comment: That's what i did, I login using admin to do the "Copy To", it's still greyed. It's documented by MS that they disable it on Win7 on purpose.

Comment: @faulty - first time I have heard of this :/ Can you show me the article from MS?

Comment: I saw it here http://www.bluemoonpcrepair.com/wp/?p=39 under Potential Issues, the original post is http://blogs.technet.com/deploymentguys/archive/2009/10/29/configuring-default-user-settings-full-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to move the files manually to the new domain profile.

Answer (score 0):

Files & Settings Transfer wizard is probably a step above manually copying