# Official way to copy a user profile from a local account to a domain account

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, windows-domain

I have a PC in a windows domain. This PC has a local administrator account from the user who used it before the PC was joined to the domain. Now I want to migrate this users profile and settings do a domain account.

I've found several ways of doing so, including [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/75154/how-to-join-domain-and-still-maintain-settings-from-unjoined-user-profile) which does [not work](https://superuser.com/questions/104779/is-there-a-way-to-change-windows-local-account-profile-to-a-domain-account-profi#comment362153_104784) for windows 7, [one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15637.how-to-migrate-windows-user-profile-to-new-account.aspx) which requires external tools and [one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24026.step-by-step-migrate-local-user-profile-to-domain-user-profile-with-all-settings.aspx) which requires manipulating the registry. I'm looking for a (more) *official* way to do this.

Comment: Why not use the in-built Windows Easy Transfer utility? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735227, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928634

Comment: The TechNet one not *official* enough? IMO, Techie007's suggestion is the most logical.

Comment: @Techie007: EasyTransfer copies the files to an easytransfer file and then to the target users profile which needs free space on the internal hard drive of the twice size of the old users profile. For large profiles, I would need to use an external harddrive which might be even slower than copying all the files locally. I thought of a solution which just moves the files.

Comment: @CharlieRB: The cited Technet pages are actually wiki articles written by other users, not official microsoft documentation. Also, I doubt fiddling in the registry will work on larger rollouts seemlessly.

Comment: Fair enough about the TechNet article. You said "*larger rollouts*" in you comment. So, you are looking for an solution for more than one use. Those details are important when asking the question. This is not really a place to ask about corporate IT issues.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Your second link helped, thanks. It's MS officialy telling me to use easytransfer. Earlier, I only found sources of random internet guys saying that. Thanks.