# Map Windows account/Profile to Domain Account

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, windows-domain

I am using windows 7 Ultimate with user name MyNameWinAc And Pass1 as password. It has visual studio, Office and various other soft-wares installed. They have their own history and configurations.

Now I have to add this machine in a domain. User name and password of Domain user is same as my local username and  password. When I added my machine to the domain it created a new profile and as expected after login I cannot access my history and preferences and configurations of various softwares.

Is there any way so that I can configure my machine so that When ever I use domain\MyNameWinAc  I am get logged into local\MyNameWinAc environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to migrate local user to domain user?](http://superuser.com/questions/76897/how-to-migrate-local-user-to-domain-user)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, but what you can do is reboot the machine, login with a local admin account, right click My Computer, Properties, Advanced System Settings, Advanced tab, Settings under User Profiles and copy your local profile over the new profile using the Copy To... button

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MoveUser](http://tacklebox.cns.ohiou.edu/Moveuser/) to migrate all your settings to your new domain account.