# Reassociating profile with domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003, domain, user-profiles

I have a Windows 7 machine that has been part of a Windows 2003 SBS domain for well over a year now.

When I arrived back to work today from about two weeks off, I powered up my machine and tried to log in with my domain credentials, Windows made a new profile for me.  My original profile still exists, but I cannot associate it with my domain login anymore.

I have tried leaving/joining the domain, but that didn't fix it, and my system properties show that my machine is on the domain.

Is there a way I can reassociate my profile with the domain?  I have admin rights on the local machine and on the domain, and I can access the domain controller, so I can do whatever I need.

Should I just go through the steps outlined in [How to migrate local user to domain user?](https://superuser.com/questions/76897/how-to-migrate-local-user-to-domain-user)  Try [Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer)?

Comment: Does your account still show up in Active Directory Users and Computers? I'm guessing this was not a roaming profile. Does the old profile still show up in the Users folder? Can you log on to it locally?

Comment: @r.tanner.f  Old profile is still in C:\Users, and I can login locally.  Not a roaming profile.  The user in AD appears fine; I can RDC into the domain controller with my domain credentials, and all of the group memberships looks fine.  Outlook/Exchange still works, too.

Comment: do an ipconfig /all, and make sure your Connection-Specific DNS Suffix is your local domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your local profile has become disassociated from your account. You can try this to fix it:

1. While logged in with your domain account on the computer with containing your "broken" profile, run the following at a command prompt: `whoami /user`. Take note of the SID value.
2. Reboot and log back in with a different account with local admin rights on this computer.
3. Launch regedit and browse to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`. Select the key named for your SID from step one.
4. The `ProfileImagePath` value is probably pointing to the wrong path. Enter the correct value to your original profile path.
5. Log out and log back in with your original domain account. Your profile should load properly.

Comment: This will associate the proper home directory for the domain user, but my "local" account is otherwise OK.  This would mean I would lose my registry settings, correct, since they are associate with the profile for the other SID?

Comment: To clarify, you have a domain user 'domain\username' (sid: S-1-5-12345678-23456789-34567890-567) that you are have been using to log into a computer that is joined to the 'domain' domain. You are still able to log into that computer with domain\username's credentials, but have lost access to the profile you have been using (i.e. c:\users\username) and instead get c:\users\temp as your profile. If that sounds about right, the steps above should re-associate your profile back to your account.