# How long can a workstation be not connect to domain before getting locked out?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, windows-domain

I used a personal laptop at a company for a while and the laptop was joined to their domain. I have since left the company and the laptop is home with me. I heavily use the domain profile that was created when I joined their domain and right now it wouldn't be possible to recreate a new profile and migrate my apps to a local profile.

whats the consequences of not ever leaving the domain? Will there come a time when I will be unable to log in again? Can I convert this this domain profile to a local profile?

Comment: Semi-duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/76897/how-to-migrate-local-user-to-domain-user

Comment: @Zac B Not the same, IMO. This asks about cached credentials. Question could be renamed to "how long can cached credentials be used for?"

Comment: Hi Jake, have you tried creating a local profile, and simply copying the Desktop/My Documents/etc to the local profile? And these APPs you speak of, were they only installed for the domain profile, and they wouldnt be in the Start Menu of any local profiles, or the ability to dig through the hard drive to create a shortcut? Just curious because I have dealt with Mortgage software clients that connect to an external server that is available for all users, regardless if they are on a domain or have local accounts.

Answer (score 1):

When you log on away from the domain you are using cached credentials. There is no timeout for these credentials so you should be fine.

Bear in mind though... If your laptop goes kaput and needs its OS rebulding, you could struggle. To counter this, you'll need a bare-metal backup (a full disk image), or take the preventative measures you mentioned in your post.

The profile is linked to your domain user account and will be working on a local copy. It can often be exported to be accessed by others, but I'm not sure if it would really work in this case.